# Dudas con Python Wheels

Tags: python, pip

Leyendo un poco sobre `pip` me tope con los llamados paquetes `wheel`. Entré a la pagina oficial de wheel y trate de investigar un poco en otras paginas pero realmente no me quedan claras varias cosas:

- ¿Wheel es un 'manejador de paquetes' o un formato de estos?
- ¿Qué son los llamados `eggs` ? (algún tipo de paquetes por lo que veo)
- ¿Wheel es un modulo? y de ser así ¿Ya viene instalado en python(3.8) por defecto?
- ¿Cuándo usar wheel?

De antemano gracias.

https://pythonwheels.com/

Comment: Wheel es un **formato** de paquetes. En la página [https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2015/07/empaquetado-y-distribucion-de-proyectos.html](https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2015/07/empaquetado-y-distribucion-de-proyectos.html) explican este tema bastante bien. En resumen, existen dos tipos de paquetes Python: 1. Los paquetes **source**, que se compilan al instalarlos.
2. Los paquetes **wheel**, que ya están pre-compilados y por tanto se instalan más rápidamente. En general es recomendable utilizar wheel. El instalador PIP ya se encarga de gestionar ambos tipos de paquetes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La documentación oficial dice:

> PIP es un administrador de paquetes para paquetes de Python, o módulos
> si lo desea.

Para saber si tienes instalado wheel teclea en una terminal:

```
pip list
```

Mostrará una lista. Si ves wheel, entonces ya está instalado.

Te podría servir echar un vistazo a https://pypi.org/project/wheel/ y ver qué es wheel.

> Esta biblioteca es la implementación de referencia del estándar de empaquetado de ruedas Python, como se define en PEP 427.
>
> Tiene dos roles diferentes:

```
  Una extensión de setuptools para construir ruedas que proporciona el comando bdist_wheel setuptools
  Una herramienta de línea de comandos para trabajar con archivos de rueda
```

> Cabe señalar que la rueda no está diseñada para usarse como una
> biblioteca y, como tal, no existe una API pública estable.

Espero haber ayudado a aclarar tus dudas.